# How can I get Visual Studio CTRL-K-D to not unroll getters and setters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

The style guides in my shop suggests formatting simple getters and setters like this:

```
string foo { get; set; }
```

I find the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> unrolls them like this

```
string foo
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio not do do this, specifically for getters and setter?

Comment: If it's already compact (e.g. `string foo { get; set; }`) VS doesn't unroll them. At least not on my machine.

Comment: I have ReSharper installed... does that impact ctrl-k-d?

Comment: That's possible. I don't use ReSharper personally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At work, using VS2008

Take a look at tools > options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Wrapping > Leave block on Single Line

VS 2010 might be slightly different

Comment: Same in VS2010 and VS2012.

Comment: Awesomeness... that seems to have done the trick. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me (4 min away)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the confirmation on VS2010 & VS2012, as usual I have the old stuff at work including VS2005 and VS2003. Just killing time before I head to Bible study (going home takes too long).